# How do I remove/omit the count column from the dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably very simple, but I've searched for hours and I can't find how to remove/omit column 1 (count column) in pandas?

Currently looks like:

```
    ID     Test1    Test2   Test3
1   236    data1    data2   data3   
2   323    data4    data5   data3
3   442    data6    data2   data4
4   543    data8    data2   data3
5   676    data1    data8   data4
```

Needs to look like:

```
ID     Test1    Test2   Test3
236    data1    data2   data3   
323    data4    data5   data3
442    data6    data2   data4
543    data8    data2   data3
676    data1    data8   data4
```

Code Snippet:

```
df = df[['ID','Test1','Test2','Test3']]
df.sort_values(['ID'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)
return render_template('index.html', data=df.to_html(index_names=False))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use a specific column as your index then you just use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index):

```
In [24]:
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df

Out[24]:
     Test1  Test2  Test3
ID                      
236  data1  data2  data3
323  data4  data5  data3
442  data6  data2  data4
543  data8  data2  data3
676  data1  data8  data4
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the ID column the index:

```
    df = df.set_index('ID')
```

Answer (score 2):

Next possible solution is add parameter `index=False` [`to_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) for no write `index`:

```
return render_template('index.html', data=df.to_html(index_names=False, index=False))
```

> **index** : bool, optional
>
> whether to print index (row) labels, default True

Output of sample:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Test1</th>
      <th>Test2</th>
      <th>Test3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>236</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>323</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>442</td>
      <td>data6</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>543</td>
      <td>data8</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>676</td>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data8</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```